# SWR: immediately update UI when mutating data

Tags: reactjs, next.js, swr

I want the data in the UI to update immediately rather than waiting for SWR to sync with the database.

I've tried following [the docs](https://swr.vercel.app/docs/mutation#mutation-and-post-request), but the UI still won't update automatically (I switch away and back to my browser to update it). Here's the code:

```js
import useSWR, { useSWRConfig } from "swr";

export default function Tasks() {
  const { mutate } = useSWRConfig()
  const { data } = useSWR("/api/tasks", (...args) =>
    fetch(...args).then((res) => res.json())
  )

  const deleteTask = async (taskId) => {
    const newData = data.filter((task) => task.id !== taskId)

    mutate(`/api/tasks/${taskId}`, newData, false)

    await fetch(`/api/tasks/${taskId}`, {
      method: "DELETE",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    })

    mutate(`/api/tasks/${taskId}`)
  }

  if (!data) return <p>loading</p>

  return (
    <div>
      {data.map((task) => (
        <div key={task.id}>
          <div>{task.content}</div>
          <button onClick={() => deleteTask(task.id)}>Delete</button>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that your are calling the wrong mutate function. You are expecting `data` to get refreshed while you are calling mutate on `` mutate(`/api/tasks/${taskId}`) ``

First, make the following modification

```
const { data, mutate: mutateList } = useSWR("/api/tasks", (...args) =>
    fetch(...args).then((res) => res.json())
 )
```

Now, in your `delete task` do the following

```
const deleteTask = async (taskId) => {
    const newData = data.filter((task) => task.id !== taskId)

   // The useSWR("/api/tasks"...) returns a mutate method bound to swr's key, use it! 
   // Passing false will prevent revalidation so a fetch request 
   // won't be made to your api on the other hand if you pass true 
   // then a fetch request will be made to your api. In both cases
   // you should see your cache refreshed immediately and that
   // should update your UI. Since you haven't as yet updated your
   // backend i.e. you are calling mutate _before_ calling your 
   // api, you'll want to pass false as 2nd argument. 
   // Had you called mutate after calling your api then you could 
   // have passed true as second argument to revalidate your cached
   // data. Passing true as second argument in the function below
   // doesn't make sense since you have yet to update your 
   // server/backend.
    await mutateList(newData, false);

    await fetch(`/api/tasks/${taskId}`, {
      method: "DELETE",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    })         
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you read more of the doc page you can find the bounded mutate, it's function returned by useSWR hook. and its the easiest way to revalidate the data. the [doc](https://swr.vercel.app/docs/mutation#bound-mutate)

```
  const { data, mutate } = useSWR('/api/user', fetcher)
  ...
  mutate() //run mutation
```